# One of the best way to convert tableView into mutiple pages PDF in Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdf

Use this function to get mutiple pages pdf Version of your tableView, just pass your tableView name to this function :-

```
func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) {


        let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
        let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height))
        tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height)
        let pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
        var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
        while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY)
            tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
            pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        tableView.bounds = priorBounds

        var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last! as NSURL
        docURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myDocument.pdf")
        pdfData.writeToURL(docURL, atomically: true)
    }
```

Comment: Does this clip any cells when you get to the end of the page?

Answer (score 14):

Update with swift

```
   func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) {    
        let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
        let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height))
        tableView.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)
        let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)    
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
        var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
        while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
            tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
            pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        tableView.bounds = priorBounds
        var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDocument.pdf")
        pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)
    }
```

Comment: This works when all cells have the same height, but if height is dynamic, it's only loading part of the table view. Do you have a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: @K.Wu i got the same problem!! have u found any thing?

Comment: @ItanHant Yes. Reason why this is happening is that UITableView's `contentSize`  does not always give the correct size of its content. It's calculated by `estimatedRowHeight`. However, you cannot set the estimated row height to a fixed number because that gives you the same problem. The only way to make `contentSize` accurate is by loading all cells at least once. You can do that by scrolling through all cells. I'm sure you can find a solution online that tells you how to do this.

Comment: Excellent needed this

Answer (score 2):

In order to make [Raj Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41671812/5479510) solution render the whole table with different cell heights, you need to change content offset of the table view on each render cycle.

The full snippet:

```swift
func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) {    
  let priorBounds = tableView.bounds

  let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(
    width: priorBounds.size.width, 
    height: tableView.contentSize.height
  ))

  tableView.bounds = CGRect(
    x: 0, y: 0,
    width: fittedSize.width,
    height: fittedSize.height
  )

  let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(
    x :0, y: 0,
    width: tableView.frame.width, 
    height: self.view.frame.height
  )    

  let pdfData = NSMutableData()
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)

  var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
  while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
    tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
    pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: pageOriginY) // move "renderer"
  }
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

  tableView.bounds = priorBounds
  var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
  docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDocument.pdf")
  pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITableView{

    func exportAsPdfFromTable() -> String? {
        //Render entire tableview content as UIImage and put it in UIImageView
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.contentSize, false, 0)
        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let interationCount: Int = Int(ceil(self.contentSize.height / self.bounds.size.height))
        for i in 0..<interationCount {
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(self.bounds.size.height) * i), animated: false)
            self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        }

        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        let pdfImg: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if let pdfData = self.createPDFFromUIView(pdfImg: pdfImg){
            let data = NSMutableData(data: pdfData)
            return saveTablePdf(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }

    //Convert UIImageView(which contains image of pdf) to pdf
    private func createPDFFromUIView(pdfImg: UIView) -> Data? {
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfImg.bounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        pdfImg.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        return pdfData.copy() as? Data
    }

    // Save pdf file in document directory
    func saveTablePdf(data: NSMutableData) -> String {

        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("tablePdf.pdf")
        if data.write(to: pdfPath, atomically: true) {
            return pdfPath.path
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).